# Programmatically combine CRL with delta CRL in C# or Java

Tags: pki, ocsp, eid

I'm searching for an implementation in **C#** or **Java** of the algorithm to combine **CRL** with **delta** **CRL** as described in *RFC5280*.

I'm working on *web authentication* with the *portuguese eID* **smart card** *"Cartão de Cidadão"* and other similar tokens with authentication certificates which have **CRL** and **delta-CRL**.

In our system we do not use **SSL** renegotiation for very specific security reasons (*web applications are also used in citizen presential support and the **SSL** authentication of the user agent forces the systematic close of all instances between each different authentication*).

We are using **OCSP**, but now we have also to programmatically check certificates' validity in some specific cases using **CRL** and **delta CRL** .

Can anyone please direct me to a correct path to avoid reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Do you find the solution in java?

Comment: We did not found an implementation as we posted here, but we ended by not implementing the algorithm suggested in the RFC. Instead, we found a simple solution for our problem: we search for a certificate latest state by looking up for it first in the latest delta-CRL and, if it doesn't exists in the delta-CRL, then we repeat the search in the CRL.

Comment: Yes I know the Delta_CRL approach, however I think the OCSP is much more better due to scalability and stability.